# Programing in Latex, if and?

Tags: programming

I know about `\ifthenelse`. Is it possible to programming in LaTeX like in C, with loops and arrays?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Note that TeX is a macro processing language so a better comparison is with the C preprocessor and `#ifdef` constructs than with `C`

Comment: TeX is Turing complete, so all of these things are possible. However, it's probably better to ask about specific things you want to achive: we've got some general questions on for example conditional constructions already. It's possible that what you want has already been covered or is best handled in TeX in a different way from for example C.

Comment: arrays in LaTeX... cruel joke